# Equivalence of two types without consideing type parameters

Tags: scala, macros, types, implicit

I want some implicit evidence that appears as follows:

```
def foo[A, B](implicit ev: ???[A, B]) = ev

foo[Int, Int] //○ (compiles)
foo[Any, Int] //× (fails)
foo[Seq[Int], Seq[Int]] //○
foo[Seq[Any], Seq[Int]] //○
foo[Seq[Int], List[Int]] //×
```

So two types must be of the same class, but their type parameters don't matter (just like `ClassTag`.) How do you implement such function? Do you use macro?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend answered outside XD

```
sealed trait ~[A, B]
object ~ {
  implicit def a[A, B](implicit ev: A =:= B) = new ~[A, B] {}
  implicit def fa[F[_], A, B] = new ~[F[A], F[B]] {}
}
```

run:

```
scala> implicitly[Int ~ Int]
res0: ~[Int,Int] = $tilde$$anon$1@574ae207

scala> implicitly[Int ~ Any]
<console>:10: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: ~[Int,Any]
              implicitly[Int ~ Any]
                        ^

scala> implicitly[Seq[Int] ~ Seq[Any]]
res2: ~[Seq[Int],Seq[Any]] = $tilde$$anon$2@27dc1857

scala> implicitly[Seq[Int] ~ Seq[Int]]
res3: ~[Seq[Int],Seq[Int]] = $tilde$$anon$2@69c33436

scala> implicitly[Seq[Int] ~ List[Int]]
<console>:10: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: ~[Seq[Int],List[Int]]
              implicitly[Seq[Int] ~ List[Int]]
                        ^
```

Comment: great! Should add for type constructor for more than one parameter too, `def fab[F[_, _], A1, B1, A2, B2] = ....`